# MIPS $a_ and $v_ registers producing incorrect output

Tags: mips

My code is supposed to calculate and print the sum, average, min, max, num of integers above avg, and numb of integers below avg in that order.
It is having an issue with the registers passing them in.

I've tried utilizing the $v1 register as I believed my li $v0, 1 commands were causing wrong output. This did change my output from all 1's to 2 0's and the rest 1's.
here is an example of the current output with the input values numbers 1-10

```
Enter integer: 1
Enter integer: 2
Enter integer: 3
Enter integer: 4
Enter integer: 5
Enter integer: 6
Enter integer: 7
Enter integer: 8
Enter integer: 9
Enter integer: 10
Sum: 55
Average: 55
Minimum: 1
Maximum: 10
Number of integers above: 0
Number of integers below: 0
```

here is the code

```
.data
array:      .space 40  # 10 integers * 4 bytes = 40 byte array
newline:    .asciiz "\n"
userPrompt: .asciiz "Enter integer: "
print_sum_statement:    .asciiz "Sum: "
print_avg_statement:    .asciiz "Average: "
print_max_statement:    .asciiz "Maximum: "
print_min_statement:    .asciiz "Minimum: "
print_above_statement: .asciiz "Number of integers above: "
print_below_statement:  .asciiz "Number of integers below: "
```

```
.text
main: 

# COLLECT USERINPUT
#-------------------------
    la $a0, array           # Setting the array to be passing in through $a_
    jal intRead             # Jumping to function to read in array
    move $s0, $v0           # Passes number of elements to univerally stored register
                    # Since this value should never change.
#-------------------------
```

```
# PRINT SUM BY CALLING SUM_CALC
#-------------------------
sum_print:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, print_sum_statement # Print statement
    syscall
    
    la $a0, array           # Passing in the array
    move $a1, $s0           # Passing in num elements
                    

    jal sum_calc            # Call the sum_calc function

    move $a0, $v0

    li $v0, 1
    #move $a0, $v1          # Print the sum ($v0)
    syscall

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, newline
    syscall
#------------------------
```

```
# PRINT AVERAGE BY CALLING AVG_CALC
#---------------------------
avg_print:  
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, print_avg_statement # Print statement
    syscall
    
    la $a0, array
    move $a1, $s0

    jal avg_calc            # Call avg_calc function
    
    move $v1, $v0
    move $a0, $v1

    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    
    #li $v0, 4
    #move $a0, $v1          # Print the sum ($s1 = $t3 = average holder)
    #syscall
#---------------------------
```

```
# PRINT MINIMUM VALUE BY CALLING MIN_INT
#---------------------------
min_print:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, newline
    syscall

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, print_min_statement # Print statement
    syscall
    
    la $a0, array
    move $a1, $s0   
    
    jal min_int         # Call min_int function
    
    move $a0, $v0

    li $v0, 1
    #move $a0, $v1          # Print integer minimum 
    syscall
#--------------------------
```

```
# PRINT MAXIMUM VALUE BY CALLING MAX_INT
#--------------------------
max_print:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, newline
    syscall

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, print_max_statement     # Print statement
    syscall
    
    la $a0, array
    move $a1, $s0
    
    jal max_int             # Call max_int function

    move $a0, $v0

    li $v0, 1
    #move $a0, $v1              # Print integer maximum
    syscall
#--------------------------
```

```
# PRINT NUM OF INTEGERS ABOVE AVG BY CALLING ABOVE_AVG
#--------------------------
above_avg_print:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, newline
    syscall

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, print_above_statement       # Print statement
    syscall

    la $a0, array
    move $a1, $s0               # $s0 holds the average
    move $a2, $v1
    
    jal above_avg               # Call above_avg function

    move $a0, $v0
    li $v0, 1
    
    #move $a0, $v0              # Print integer count
    syscall
#------------------------
```

```
# PRINT NUM OF INTEGERS BELOW AVG BY CALLING BELOW_AVG
#--------------------------
below_avg_print:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, newline
    syscall

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, print_below_statement       # Print statement
    syscall
    
    la $a0, array
    move $a1, $s0
    move $a2, $v1
    
    jal below_avg               # Call below_avg function

    move $a0, $v0
    li $v0, 1
    #move $a0, $v0              # Print integer count
    syscall
#------------------------
```

```
# EXIT PROGRAM
#------------------------
exit:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
#------------------------
```

```
# FUNCTIONS
#------------------------

# FUNCTION 1 - READ IN ARRAY LOOP
#------------------------
intRead:
 
    addi $sp, $sp, -4           # Allocating space on the stack to save the $ra
    sw $ra, 0($sp)              # Save return address to stack 
 
    # Setting up loop
    li $t0, 0           # Loop counter
    move $t1, $a0           # Pass the base address of the array into $t1
    li $t2, 0               # Integer counter
 
intRead_loop:
    beq $t2, 10, intRead_exit   # Break when count reaches 10

    # Prompt for userinput
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, userPrompt
    syscall

    # Read in userinput
    li $v0, 5
    syscall 
                    
    beq $v0, -9, intRead_exit   # Break when userinput is equal to -9

    sw $v0, 0($t1)          # Store word(sw) fron register $v0 (userinput) into the array at the first open location 0 

    #Increment variables
    addi $t1, $t1, 4        # Increment array address by 4 (4 bytes)
    addi $t0, $t0, 1        # Increment loop counter by 1 
    addi $t2, $t2, 1        # Increment integer count by 1

    j intRead_loop

intRead_exit:               # Exit function to save variables and stops loop to be called for printing
    move $s0, $t2             
 
    lw $ra, 0($sp)          # Load in the previous return address
    addi $sp, $sp, 4        # Deallocating space on the stack - moving $sp back/down 
    jr $ra              # Return to register address
#------------------------
```

```
# FUNCTION 2 - COMPUTE INTEGER SUM
#------------------------
sum_calc:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4           # Allocating space on the stack to save the $ra
    sw $ra, 0($sp)          # Save return address to stack 
    
    move $t1, $a0           # Moving array address back to temp register
    move $t2, $a1           # Moving numb of integers back to temp register
    
    li $t0, 0           # Redeclare $t0 as 0 for sum_loop counter   
    li $t3, 0           # declare $t3 as 0 for sum of array

    la $t1, array


sum_loop:
    beq $t0, $t2, sum_exit      # When $t0 is equal to $s0 ($t2 - integer count) break and go to sum_exit

    lw $t4, 0($t1)          # Loading the integer value into $a0

    #Increment variables
    add $t3, $t3, $t4       # Add $t3(0) to $t4(first num from array)
    addi $t1, $t1, 4
    addi $t0, $t0, 1        

    j sum_loop

sum_exit:               # Exit function to save variables and stops loop to be called for printing
    move $v0, $t3               # Saving the sum into accessable register $s1
          
    lw $ra, 0($sp)              # Load in the previous return address
    addi $sp, $sp, 4            # Deallocating space on the stack - moving $sp back/down 
    jr $ra                  # Return to register address 
#------------------------
```

```
# FUNCTION 3- AVERAGE FUNCTION (CALLING SUM_CALC)
#------------------------
avg_calc:

    addi $sp, $sp, -4       # Allocating space on the stack to save the $ra
    sw $ra, 0($sp)              # Save return address to stack 

    li $t0, 0           # Redeclare $t0 as 0 for sum_loop counter
    la $a0, array           # Redeclaring the array in the $a0 register to be passed in
    move $a1, $s0           # Moving number of intagers to $a1 so sum_calc can recieve

    jal sum_calc            # Call in the sum function rather than passing in the value through registers

    # $v0 should contains sum
    move $t2, $s0           # Using the saved integer count
    div $t3, $t3, $t2           # $v0 should contains sum
    #mflo $v0
    

avg_exit:               # Exit function to save variables and stops loop to be called for printing
    #move $s1, $t3              # Saving the sum into accessable register $s1 = $t3 = Average of the integers
    #move $s0, $t2          # Saving the sum into accessable register $s0
    move $v1, $t3
    lw $ra, 0($sp)              # Load in previous return address
    add $sp, $sp, 4         # Deallocating space on the stack - moving $sp back/down

    jr $ra                      # Return to register address 
#------------------------
```

```
# FUNCTION 4 - COMPUTE MIN OF INTEGER ARRAY
#------------------------
min_int:

    addi $sp, $sp, -4       # Allocating space on the stack to save the $ra
    sw $ra, 0($sp)              # Save return address to stack 

    move $t1, $a0           # Passing in $a0
    move $t2, $a1
    
    li $t0, 0           # redeclare $t0 as 0
    
    lw $t4, 0($t1)          # $t4 to hold initial array val ($t4 = MINIMUM)

min_int_loop:

    beq $t0, $t2, min_exit      # When $t0 is equal to $s0 ($t2 - integer count) break and go to min_exit
    lw $t5, 0($t1)          # $t5 = current val in array
    
    bge $t5, $t4, same_min      # Break if min is greater than or equal to current val
    
    move $t4, $t5           # Set MIN to current (minimum) value
    
    #Increment variables
    addi $t1, $t1, 4        # Next value in array
    addi $t0, $t0, 1        # Increment min_int_loop count 

    j min_int_loop

same_min:
    #Increment variables
    addi $t1, $t1, 4        # Next value in array
    addi $t0, $t0, 1        # Increment min_int_loop count 

    j min_int_loop
    
min_exit:               # Exit function to save variables and stops loop to be called for printing
    move $v0, $t4           # Saving the sum into accessable register $s2 = $t4 = Minimum of the integers
    lw $ra, 0($sp)              # Load in previous return address
    add $sp, $sp, 4         # Deallocating space on the stack - moving $sp back/down

    jr $ra                      # Return to register address 
#-------------------------
```

```
# FUNCTION 5 - COMPUTE MAX OF INTEGER ARRAY
#-------------------------
max_int:
    
    addi $sp, $sp, -4       # Allocating space on the stack to save the $ra
    sw $ra, 0($sp)              # Save return address to stack 

    move $t1, $a0
    move $t2, $a1
    li $t0, 0           # Redeclare $t0 
    lw $t4, 0($t1)          # $t4 to hold initial array val ($t4 = MAXIMUM)

max_int_loop:
    beq $t0, $t2, max_exit
    lw $t5, 0($t1)          # $t5 = current val in array 
    #bgt $t5, $t4, new_max      # Break if max is greater than current val
     blt $t4, $t5, new_max
    #Increment variables
    addi $t1, $t1, 4        # Next value in array
    addi $t0, $t0, 1        # Increment max_int_loop count 

    j max_int_loop

new_max:
    move $t4, $t5           # Set MAX to current (maximum) value
    
    #Increment variables
    addi $t1, $t1, 4        # Next value in array
    addi $t0, $t0, 1        # Increment max_int_loop count 

    j max_int_loop

max_exit:               # Exit function to save variables and stops loop to be called for printing
    move $v0, $t4           # Saving the sum into accessable register $s2 = $t4 = Maximum of the integers
    
    lw $ra, 0($sp)              # Load in previous return address
    add $sp, $sp, 4         # Deallocating space on the stack - moving $sp back/down

    jr $ra                      # Return to register address 
#-----------------------------
```

```
# FUNCTION 6 - NUMBER OF INTEGERS ABOVE AVERAGE
#-----------------------------
above_avg:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4       # Allocating space on the stack to save the $ra
    sw $ra, 0($sp)              # Save return address to stack 

    move $t1, $a0
    move $t2, $a1
    move $t3, $a2
    
    li $t0, 0           # Redeclare $t0 
    li $t5, 0           # Declare $t5 to hold above_count

above_avg_loop:
    beq $t0, $t2, above_avg_exit    # Break when $t0 and $s0 ($t2) are equal, go to above_avg_exit
    
    lw $t4, 0($t1)          # $t4 = current val in array 
    
    bgt $t4, $t3, is_above      # Break if less than 
    
    #Increment variables
    addi $t1, $t1, 4        # Next value in array
    addi $t0, $t0, 1        # Increment loop count 

    j above_avg_loop

is_above:
    #Increment variables
    addi $t5, $t5, 1        # Increment above_count 
    addi $t1, $t1, 4        # Next value in array
    addi $t0, $t0, 1        # Increment loop count 
    
    j above_avg_loop
    
above_avg_exit:             # Exit function to save variables and stops loop to be called for printing

    move $v0, $t5           # Saving the sum into accessable register $s4 = $t5 = Number of integers above avg
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    
    jr $ra
#-------------------------------
```

```
# FUNCTION 7 - NUMBER OF INTEGERS BELOW AVERAGE
#-----------------------------
below_avg:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4       # Allocating space on the stack to save the $ra
    sw $ra, 0($sp)              # Save return address to stack 

    move $t1, $a0
    move $t2, $a1
    move $t3, $a2
    
    li $t0, 0           # Redeclare $t0 
    li $t5, 0           # Declare $t5 to hold above_count

below_avg_loop:
    beq $t0, $t2, below_avg_exit    # Break when $t0 and ($t2) are equal, go to exit
    
    lw $t4, 0($t1)          # $t4 = current val in array 
    
    blt $t4, $t3, is_below      # break if less than 
    
    #Increment variables
    addi $t1, $t1, 4        # Next value in array
    addi $t0, $t0, 1        # Increment loop count 

    j below_avg_loop

is_below:
    #Increment variables
    addi $t5, $t5, 1        # Increment below_count 
    addi $t1, $t1, 4        # Next value in array
    addi $t0, $t0, 1        # Increment loop count 
    
    j below_avg_loop

below_avg_exit:             # Exit function to save variables and stops loop to be called for printing

    move $v0, $t5           # Saving the sum into accessable register $s3 = $t5 = Number of integers below avg
    
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    add $sp, $sp, 4
    
    jr $ra
#-------------------------------
```

Comment: `intRead` returns the count in `$s0`, but your mainline seems to expect it in `$v1`.  You immediately overwrite `$s0` with `$v1`, which has garbage.

Comment: I saw this, I was messing with it and now i've gotten my sum, average and min to work. 
stuck now on max and above and below. Any ideas?

I've edited my code to the newest version, along with the new output.

Comment: i just tried new numbers and the only correct one is the min

Comment: able to fix min, with a similar issue

Comment: You're just not being careful.  `max_int` returns a value in `$v0`, but `print_max` expects it in `$v1`.  You need to have a STANDARD and FOLLOW IT.

Comment: Yes, I'm a bit brain fried but caught that almost a soon as i posted this and fixed those issues. The only are in my code that i do not understand is my above and below, ive gotten 55 (printing the sum), 0 for above and 9 for below and or 10 for above 0 below

Comment: both are now zero, updated output and code

Comment: You are storing the number of elements in `$s0`, but your above'below average routines assume that `$s0` contains the average.  Also, your output shows the average as 55, but the average should be 5.